# Primefaces Datatable lost focus

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

JSF-2.1 Primefaces 3.5
I have a datatable with Filter. I need to update only data on datatable(without Filter). Because everytime when i update the datatable, i lost my focus.

I have one dialog, and the confirm button is outside the datatable's `form`

and have another question:
when i update my datatable, i lost the text in datatable's Filter. How can i fix it

Thanks

Comment: are you updating the datatable from within the same `form` or from outside of the `form`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

place hidden commandButton (`style="display:none"`) inside the `h:form` of your `datatable`

then in you confirm button use

```
onclick="$('#full_id_of_you_new_hidden_button').click(); return false;"
```

make sure that your new hidden button will do the render/update that your original button was doing...